# thymeleaf and html - apply condition th:each via select-option-dropdown

Tags: html, conditional-statements, thymeleaf, dropdown

I have a table where the content is generated by thymeleaf.

HTML code:

```
<tbody>
   <tr th:if="${transaction.paid == 1}" th:each="transaction : ${transactions}">
     <td th:text="${transaction.user_id}"></td> 
     <td th:text="${transaction.product_id}"></td>
     <td th:text="${transaction.date}"></td>
     <td>
         <span class="msg-green" th:if="${transaction.paid == 1}">Paid</span>
         <span class="msg-red" th:if="${transaction.paid == 0}">Pending</span>
     </td>
     <td>
         <a th:if="${transaction.paid == 0}" th:href="@{/pay_transaction(id=${transaction.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Pay</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to add an select-option input field where I can set a condition which is then applied to the list.

I have the condition part:

```
<tbody>
   <tr th:if="${transaction.paid == 1}" th:if="${transaction.paid == 1}" th:each="transaction : ${transactions}">
     <td th:text="${transaction.user_id}"></td> 
     <td th:text="${transaction.product_id}"></td>
     <td th:text="${transaction.date}"></td>
     <td>
         <span class="msg-green" th:if="${transaction.paid == 1}">Paid</span>
         <span class="msg-red" th:if="${transaction.paid == 0}">Pending</span>
     </td>
     <td>
         <a th:if="${transaction.paid == 0}" th:href="@{/pay_transaction(id=${transaction.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Pay</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

But I would like to have three options:

```
transaction.paid == 0
transaction.paid == 1
and all
```

Is there a way without using jquery/javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand it right, then you want to change the view, when the client change the select-option. This is not possible without a new request to server, because thymeleaf is compiled on server-site.